# Submodules in GIT

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-svn

I have clone a open source project on a server and I am willing to customize it, wanting to have some branches e.g. development, master etc... When I downloaded it on my server there were submodules which were downloaded and in .gitmodules file the name of the submodule, path and URL is mentioned. Now from my server when I clone it to my PC it still contact that URL for downloading that submodule, however I was thinking that my server which has the repository will be 100% server and that URL in the .gitmodules will not be contacted any more....

Can I have my local server  a 100% server???

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It is because the original author use full path to submodule. If relative path is used, then you can use you local submodule.

Example of Relative path:"../moduleB"

You may edit .gitmodules

Comment: I tried but it is still not working, now I am tried to change the remote URL on the local machine (not on the server). My plan is that I will edit the code on local machine and will do the push and the change code will be pushed to server.....

Comment: if ssh://127.0.0.1/git/moduleA.git, then put moduleB in ssh://127.0.0.1/git/moduleB.git